# How can I be sure that my android runnable started on a worker thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, user-interface, runnable

I am trying to learn about doing background tasks on Android/Java by using threading. I made a simple test application which purely did a new Thread(new Runnable()) and did sleeps inside the runnable. When this was running, I was still able to click on buttons on my UI (I could see the visual feedback).

Happy this was working, I moved the same code into my main application codebase, but it seems like it is still running on the UI Thread as the GUI locks up and the ANR pops up after the sleep loop is completed.

*Can anybody please help me work out why my backgroundThread is not running on a Background or Worker thread?*

**LoginService.java**

```
package com.example.services;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;

public class LoginService implements ILoginService {

private Handler handler;

public LoginService() {
    handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // Handle a message from the background task
            Log.d("LoginService","Received a Message");
        }
    };
}

/*
    Check if the username exists in the list
 */
@Override
public boolean isUsernameValid(String username) {
    Log.d("LoginService","Starting Runnable");
    Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(new LoginRunnable(this));

    backgroundThread.run();
    Log.d("LoginService", "Started Runnable");
    return true;
}

/*
    Check if the password is correct for the downloaded user
 */
@Override
public boolean doesPasswordMatch(String password) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void handleStatus(int i) {
    switch (i) {
        case 1:
            Message newMessage = handler.obtainMessage();
            newMessage.sendToTarget();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
}
```

**LoginRunnable.java**

```
package com.example.services;

import android.util.Log;

public class LoginRunnable implements Runnable {

public ILoginService loginService;

public LoginRunnable(ILoginService loginService)
{
    this.loginService = loginService;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    // Do the login tasks here
    try {
        for(int i = 0;i<=50;i++) {
            Thread.sleep(200);
            Log.d("LoginRunnable","200ms has passed");
            loginService.handleStatus(1);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Return some completion message to the LoginService.

}
}
```

**Output from App**

```
11-08 18:06:36.757  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginService﹕ Starting Runnable
11-08 18:06:36.971  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginRunnable﹕ 200ms has passed
11-08 18:06:37.181  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginRunnable﹕ 200ms has passed
11-08 18:06:37.391  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginRunnable﹕ 200ms has passed
11-08 18:06:37.601  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginRunnable﹕ 200ms has passed
11-08 18:06:37.811  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginRunnable﹕ 200ms has passed
11-08 18:06:38.021  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginRunnable﹕ 200ms has passed
11-08 18:06:38.231  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginRunnable﹕ 200ms has passed
11-08 18:06:38.441  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginRunnable﹕ 200ms has passed
11-08 18:06:38.652  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginRunnable﹕ 200ms has passed
11-08 18:06:38.861  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginRunnable﹕ 200ms has passed
11-08 18:06:39.072  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginRunnable﹕ 200ms has passed
11-08 18:06:39.282  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginRunnable﹕ 200ms has passed
11-08 18:06:39.492  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginRunnable﹕ 200ms has passed
11-08 18:06:39.701  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginRunnable﹕ 200ms has passed
11-08 18:06:39.912  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginRunnable﹕ 200ms has passed
11-08 18:06:40.121  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginRunnable﹕ 200ms has passed
11-08 18:06:40.332  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginRunnable﹕ 200ms has passed
11-08 18:06:40.542  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginRunnable﹕ 200ms has passed
11-08 18:06:40.752  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginRunnable﹕ 200ms has passed
11-08 18:06:40.962  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginRunnable﹕ 200ms has passed
11-08 18:06:41.172  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginRunnable﹕ 200ms has passed
11-08 18:06:41.381  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginRunnable﹕ 200ms has passed
11-08 18:06:41.592  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginRunnable﹕ 200ms has passed
11-08 18:06:41.802  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginRunnable﹕ 200ms has passed
11-08 18:06:42.012  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginRunnable﹕ 200ms has passed
11-08 18:06:42.222  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginRunnable﹕ 200ms has passed
11-08 18:06:42.432  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginRunnable﹕ 200ms has passed
11-08 18:06:42.642  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginRunnable﹕ 200ms has passed
11-08 18:06:42.851  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginRunnable﹕ 200ms has passed
11-08 18:06:43.062  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginRunnable﹕ 200ms has passed
11-08 18:06:43.272  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginRunnable﹕ 200ms has passed
11-08 18:06:43.482  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginRunnable﹕ 200ms has passed
11-08 18:06:43.692  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginRunnable﹕ 200ms has passed
11-08 18:06:43.902  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginRunnable﹕ 200ms has passed
11-08 18:06:44.112  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginRunnable﹕ 200ms has passed
11-08 18:06:44.322  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginRunnable﹕ 200ms has passed
11-08 18:06:44.532  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginRunnable﹕ 200ms has passed
11-08 18:06:44.741  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginRunnable﹕ 200ms has passed
11-08 18:06:44.952  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginRunnable﹕ 200ms has passed
11-08 18:06:45.162  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginRunnable﹕ 200ms has passed
11-08 18:06:45.372  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginRunnable﹕ 200ms has passed
11-08 18:06:45.582  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginRunnable﹕ 200ms has passed
11-08 18:06:45.792  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginRunnable﹕ 200ms has passed
11-08 18:06:46.002  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginRunnable﹕ 200ms has passed
11-08 18:06:46.212  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginRunnable﹕ 200ms has passed
11-08 18:06:46.422  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginRunnable﹕ 200ms has passed
11-08 18:06:46.632  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginRunnable﹕ 200ms has passed
11-08 18:06:46.842  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginRunnable﹕ 200ms has passed
11-08 18:06:47.052  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginRunnable﹕ 200ms has passed
11-08 18:06:47.262  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginRunnable﹕ 200ms has passed
11-08 18:06:47.472  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginRunnable﹕ 200ms has passed
11-08 18:06:47.472  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginService﹕ Started Runnable
11-08 18:06:47.482  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginService﹕ Received a Message
11-08 18:06:47.482  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginService﹕ Received a Message
11-08 18:06:47.483  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginService﹕ Received a Message
11-08 18:06:47.483  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginService﹕ Received a Message
11-08 18:06:47.483  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginService﹕ Received a Message
11-08 18:06:47.483  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginService﹕ Received a Message
11-08 18:06:47.483  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginService﹕ Received a Message
11-08 18:06:47.483  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginService﹕ Received a Message
11-08 18:06:47.483  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginService﹕ Received a Message
11-08 18:06:47.483  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginService﹕ Received a Message
11-08 18:06:47.483  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginService﹕ Received a Message
11-08 18:06:47.484  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginService﹕ Received a Message
11-08 18:06:47.484  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginService﹕ Received a Message
11-08 18:06:47.484  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginService﹕ Received a Message
11-08 18:06:47.484  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginService﹕ Received a Message
11-08 18:06:47.484  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginService﹕ Received a Message
11-08 18:06:47.484  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginService﹕ Received a Message
11-08 18:06:47.484  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginService﹕ Received a Message
11-08 18:06:47.484  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginService﹕ Received a Message
11-08 18:06:47.484  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginService﹕ Received a Message
11-08 18:06:47.484  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginService﹕ Received a Message
11-08 18:06:47.484  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginService﹕ Received a Message
11-08 18:06:47.484  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginService﹕ Received a Message
11-08 18:06:47.485  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginService﹕ Received a Message
11-08 18:06:47.485  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginService﹕ Received a Message
11-08 18:06:47.485  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginService﹕ Received a Message
11-08 18:06:47.485  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginService﹕ Received a Message
11-08 18:06:47.485  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginService﹕ Received a Message
11-08 18:06:47.485  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginService﹕ Received a Message
11-08 18:06:47.485  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginService﹕ Received a Message
11-08 18:06:47.485  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginService﹕ Received a Message
11-08 18:06:47.485  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginService﹕ Received a Message
11-08 18:06:47.485  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginService﹕ Received a Message
11-08 18:06:47.485  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginService﹕ Received a Message
11-08 18:06:47.485  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginService﹕ Received a Message
11-08 18:06:47.485  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginService﹕ Received a Message
11-08 18:06:47.486  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginService﹕ Received a Message
11-08 18:06:47.486  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginService﹕ Received a Message
11-08 18:06:47.486  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginService﹕ Received a Message
11-08 18:06:47.486  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginService﹕ Received a Message
11-08 18:06:47.486  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginService﹕ Received a Message
11-08 18:06:47.486  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginService﹕ Received a Message
11-08 18:06:47.486  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginService﹕ Received a Message
11-08 18:06:47.486  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginService﹕ Received a Message
11-08 18:06:47.486  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginService﹕ Received a Message
11-08 18:06:47.486  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginService﹕ Received a Message
11-08 18:06:47.486  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginService﹕ Received a Message
11-08 18:06:47.486  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginService﹕ Received a Message
11-08 18:06:47.487  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginService﹕ Received a Message
11-08 18:06:47.487  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginService﹕ Received a Message
11-08 18:06:47.487  11722-11722/com.example  D/LoginService﹕ Received a Message
```

**Output from Working Test Program (Seperate Project)**

```
11-08 17:57:31.284  32596-32610/com.subarudev.threadingtest D/SleepRunnable﹕ Sleeping on thread
11-08 17:57:31.284  32596-32596/com.subarudev.threadingtest D/MainActivity﹕ Handle Message
11-08 17:57:31.493  32596-32610/com.subarudev.threadingtest D/SleepRunnable﹕ Sleeping on thread
11-08 17:57:31.494  32596-32596/com.subarudev.threadingtest D/MainActivity﹕ Handle Message
11-08 17:57:31.704  32596-32610/com.subarudev.threadingtest D/SleepRunnable﹕ Sleeping on thread
11-08 17:57:31.704  32596-32596/com.subarudev.threadingtest D/MainActivity﹕ Handle Message
11-08 17:57:31.914  32596-32610/com.subarudev.threadingtest D/SleepRunnable﹕ Sleeping on thread
11-08 17:57:31.914  32596-32596/com.subarudev.threadingtest D/MainActivity﹕ Handle Message
11-08 17:57:32.123  32596-32610/com.subarudev.threadingtest D/SleepRunnable﹕ Sleeping on thread
11-08 17:57:32.124  32596-32596/com.subarudev.threadingtest D/MainActivity﹕ Handle Message
11-08 17:57:32.334  32596-32610/com.subarudev.threadingtest D/SleepRunnable﹕ Sleeping on thread
11-08 17:57:32.334  32596-32596/com.subarudev.threadingtest D/MainActivity﹕ Handle Message
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

backgroundThread.run() - >  backgroundThread.start()?